# How to overide CSS style of a class using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to override a class style but I can't figure out how to do it.
I know about the `addClass` function which is available in jQuery to add a class but I cannot find any function that overrides a style of a class not the whole class.

Is there any way possible to override the style?

Comment: Make you of css specificity!

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy what do you mean

Comment: You mean to say you would like to override certain style of a class?

Comment: @garden Check my answer to solve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply provide a new style

```
$("body").css("background-color", "red");
```

**Demo :**

```js
function Change() {
    $("body").css("background-color", "black");
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: red;
  color: #0000ff;
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>This is some paragraph text</p>
<button onclick="Change()">Change bgcolor without affecting other styles</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

By using jQuery's addClass() function and the CSS rule of specificity (here the class further down in the stylesheet gains specificity), you can override a single style rule:

```js
$('.box').click(function(){
    $('.box').addClass('yellow');  
});
```

```css
.box{
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    background:lightblue;
    display:flex;
    justify-content:center;
    align-items:center;
    cursor:pointer;
}

.yellow{
    background-color:yellow;  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box">Click Me!<div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to override a particular style of a class, you can add another class and assign it to your item.
For example, if you have a class like-

```
.new-item {
    background-color: #e1e1e1;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

Then you can write another class like-

```
.updated-item {
    background-color: white !important;
}
```

And then simply `addClass('updated-item')` to your item using jQuery.

Comment: And what happens with old class and styles  when I add new one to html element?

Comment: @ksno Only the styles mentioned in the .updated-item class will be overridden, the rest of the styles will still be taken from the .new-item class, since we are only adding a new class and not removing the previous class styles.

Answer (score 0):

To override CSS rules, you need to understand the CSS specificity. Classes have less specificity than IDs which has less specificity than inline CSS.

Either add inline CSS using `.css()` function of jQuery or add ID to that element or make use of `!important`.

Answer (score 0):

Overriding the style can be done without jQuery functions.
the style get applied according to the following priority:

**Style on a separate CSS file**

```
.className{
  color:#eee;
}
```

**Style ordering**

```
.className{
  color:#eee;
}
.className{
  color:#fff; /* this will override the previous one */
}
```

**More specific selector**

```
#id.className{
  color:#fff;
}
```

**important**

```
#id.className{
  color:#000 !important;
}
```

**style in head tag**

```
<style>
  .className{
    color:#000 !important;
  }
</style>
```

**Inline style**

```
<p style='color:#ff0;'>Hello World!</p>
```